# MS Reporting Service 2008 R2 - table awfully slow

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Using Reporting Service to render the result of an MDX Query the result is awfully slow (around 8-10 seconds). The MDX is fast, there is indeed some conditional rendering but 8 secons sounds like an awfull amount of time for a 60x10 Table.

We played with the Can Grow/Shrink but the slow performance is still there.

Does somebody had the same experience, the performance is a general SSRS problem or are we adding some 'feature' that is causing this bottleneck ?

Comment: Try running a profiler against the SSAS and watch your SSRS rendering process - it can help you with pinpointing the troublemaker, if there's something else, unexpected, running under the hood.

Comment: The problem is not SSAS (granted), how can I 'watch' the SSRS rendering process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a general answer. I have a few examples that decrease performance.

- Enabling CanGrow.
- Having formulas in tablixes, especially lookups.
- Groupings.
- Sorting.

It is highly recomended to use the query to order, group, summing, etc. basically any data manipulation.

Not really sure what you've got in your report.

Hope some of these help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was as pointed out in another answer, it was the canGrow. But it's a bit tricky. How we manage to solve the problem :

1) Use a browser debugger (F12 in IE) and profile the java script code. If the issue is a grow problem you'll see a method with with grow in the name taking almost all the time.

2) Better than editing all cell's properties replace in the rdl documents directly. In our case remove all'true' entries with a standard text editor (e.g Notepad++).

3) Recheck again, there could be still some cangrow that in our example are due to icons that are not so easy to remove but the improvement was massive.